# Rails button_to parameter confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to shove many parameters into a button_to method, but to no avail. I'm currently using the rails docs to see the parameters it can support -- but I'm having trouble.

[link to api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

```
<%= button_to 'My title.',{:action => "update", :answer => "!!===@@@", :method => :patch, :data => {:confirm => "Are you sure?"}}, {:class => "btn btn-danger"}%>
```

I'm looking to add some html classes to the button, redefine its HTTP method, and call a javascript prompt box (through :data, :confirm) and also add an :answer parameter to the submission content.

I'm just having trouble getting rails to parse all this correctly.

Comment: Whoa.  I take it this button is part of a form?  If so you can dictate the action in the form header (which will remove the need to dictate an action and http method.  The params "answer" is special to that one button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"As it explains on this page http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html
, extra params (such as :answer in your case) can be passed with the :params option.

The second argument needs to be something that can be resolved into a full path, like "/foos/123/update".  You can do this with `{:action => "update", :id => foo.id}`: in this case rails will use the current controller to work out which controller to use in the url.  Personally i think it's cleaner to be explicit and use a path helper like `update_foo_path(foo)` or whatever, which will just generate the full path as a string oike `"/foos/123/update"`.

Try something like this:

```
<%= button_to 'My title.', {:action => "update", :id => foo.id}, :params => {:answer => "!!===@@@"}, :method => :patch, :form_class => "btn btn-danger", :data => {:confirm => "Are you sure?"} %>
```

button_to is kind of a pain in the ass because it has this list of arguments which are all hashes or single key-value pairs and it's really easy to get the structure wrong.  I would tend to avoid them for anything complicated, and use form_tag instead: it's much more readable and less likely to go wrong.